# How to do a factory reset on Xperia Z with broken screen?

Tags: factory-reset, broken-screen

The screen on my Sony Xperia Z is cracked. I have now sold the phone so I need to delete my text messages, can anyone help?

I can only press in certain areas of the screen so I can't click on factory reset or delete messages one by one.

Comment: Are you able to press your home keys and stuff? I mean the bottom panel keys, all of them.

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to factory reset for unrooted phone is to perform a factory reset via pc companion.

1. Download [PC COMPANION](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/) and install
2. Open up PC companion and click on Software Repair
3. Optional: If your screen is locked and you can't unlock it, check the "I can't start my device"-checkbox in the lower left corner. Click "Next".
4. It will say could not find phone because you haven't connect it yet! so, do connect it and click on the repair phone like this picture. Follow onscreen instruction.

[image]

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after about 30 minutes. It's been much easier with all my other phones!

Answer (score 2):

See whether your phone supports OTG. If so, use an OTG cable and then connect the mouse to your phone. In place of touch you can now use the mouse and then reset it via normal way.

Comment: How to do that exactly?

Comment: See your phone supports otg so use an otg cable and then connect the mouse to your phone.in place of touch you can now use the mouse.voila!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you can't factory reset it via the OS, so the best thing you can do is to boot into recovery mode. This is of course as long as you can see the options on the screen. So once in recovery mode, you can select the option to factory reset the entire phone, apart from your SD card that is.

### Entering Recovery mode

1. Restart your phone.
2. When your phone's notification LED is pink, or any other colour, press the Volume UP or Volume Down button a couple of times.
3. You should now be looking at the recovery mode screen.

Once you're in recovery mode, it should be pretty easy for you to navigate up or down, using the volume buttons. Select a preferred option by pressing the Power button.

Just look for the option to reset your phone.

Sources: [www.theandroidsoul.com](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/sony-xperia-z-recovery-mode/)

Comment: This works only if op is rooted and has CWM.Sony Xperia devices don’t ship with a pre-installed recovery. So unless you’ve installed a custom recovery on your device, you won’t be able to boot into recovery mode.